# Vue Router push state without render

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router, html5-history

I would like to push a state using Vue router without triggering a rerender.

**What I want:**

- If the mobile menu is opened, a state is pushed
- This should not rerender the page
- When the user pushed the back button, a state is popped
- This should not rerender the page

[image]

What I do right now is simple pushing the same URL with a hash `#view=menu`. And removing the hash when the menu is closed. This works, however there is a big lag (due the rendering process).

How can I make sure Vue Router does not trigger a rerender in this case?

Alternatively, are there any other solutions to this use case?

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using?

Comment: as already mentioned you will need to add code. Nevertheless, my first guess would be that your structure might be the problem. If you correctly used the router-view for nesting your layout (menu) and flexible content (page) then it will only re-render the relevant parts.

Comment: vue router `keep-alive`? https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view